# Value retrieved from MongoDB is undefined when fetched by Express.js server

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

Basically what I'm trying to accomplish is pulling the data from a MongoDB database and feed it into my Express.js server. Both of these are ran on the localhost with different addresses. I have tried numerous different methods to get it working and can't seem to get it to work.

**Express portion**

```
    app.get('/products', function(request, response) {
    var query = request.query.keywords;
    var promise = new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
        var productList = await db.getProducts(query);
        resolve(productList);
    });

    promise.then(function(productList) {
        console.log(productList); // <--- productList is undefined here
        response.json({
            productList
        });     
    }).catch('Error retrieving data');
    // var productList = Promise.resolve(db.getProducts(query));
    // productList.then(products => response.json({products}));
});
```

**MongoDB portion**

```
StoreDB.prototype.getProducts = function(queryParams){
    return this.connected.then(function(db){
        // TODO: Implement functionality
        const collection = db.collection('products');
        var productList;

        if (!queryParams){
            console.log('no queryParams');
            collection.find({}).toArray(function(err, docs) {
            productList = convertToObject(docs);
            // console.log(productList); // <--- productList is defined here
            return productList;
            });
        ////////////
```

Some extra information:
- StoreDB is a functional class with only one `property` , connected, which is a promise that gets resolved once the connection to the database has been established
- The Express.js server calls `getProducts` which then resolves the promise
- Within the `getProducts` call, `productList` is defined, but when it returns, the value is undefined

With this being said, I thought that by putting the `getProducts` within in a promise, it would wait for the function call to be complete, then resolve it. However, that is not the case. Some insights would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

**SOLVED**
Thanks to @Renan Le Caro

```
app.get('/products', function(request, response, next) {
  db
    .getProducts(request.query.keywords)
    .then(productList=>response.json({productList}))
    .catch(err=>next(err));
});

StoreDB.prototype.getProducts = function(queryParams){
  return this.connected.then(db => 
    new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      db
        .collection('products')
        .find({})
        .toArray((err, docs) => err ?  reject(err) : resolve(docs))
    })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`getProducts` is already a Promise; you shouldn't need to be wrapping a Promise in another Promise, and that just opens the code up to more places things can go wrong. But `Promise.resolve` does not wait for a Promise to resolve; instead, it IMMEDIATELY returns a new Promise that has already resolved with the value you pass it. That's not what you want. And `.catch` takes a function to run when the Promise fails, not a string.

Your code should be as simple as this:

```
app.get('/products', function(request, response) {
  var query = request.query.keywords;
  db.getProducts(query).then(function(productList) {
      console.log(productList);
      response.json({
          productList
      });     
  }).catch(function() {
    response.send('Error retrieving data');
  });
});
```

Or, if you prefer the async/await syntax:

```
app.get('/products', async function(request, response) {
  var query = request.query.keywords;
  try {
  const productList = await db.getProducts(query);
      console.log(productList);
      response.json({
          productList
      });     
  } catch (err) {
    response.send('Error retrieving data');
  }
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this did not fix my issue :(

Answer (score 0):

This is just a promises misuse problem. Here's a fix (not tested).

```
app.get('/products', function(request, response, next) {
  db
    .getProducts(request.query.keywords)
    .then(productList=>response.json({productList}))
    .catch(err=>next(err));
});

StoreDB.prototype.getProducts = function(queryParams){
  return this.connected.then(db => 
    new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      db
        .collection('products')
        .find({})
        .toArray((err, docs) => err ?  reject(err) : resolve(docs))
    })
}
```

Comment: Oh wow, this actually works. Do you mind if you can explain some of this to me? Is it because when I had the promise on the Express.js side, it just executes my function but doesn't actually wait for the completion of the database call? And if you have the promise on the MongoDB side, the it ensures the data is pullled successfully and goes back to the execution of the Express.js side?

Comment: The normal approach when working with promises is : 
- when using function that expect callbacks, wrap them in the new Promise((resolve, reject) => ()) thing, so that they now return a working promise. 
- when making a functions that uses promises, always start by returning your first promise  and chaining ".then" calls to it.

Also your catch("some string") is just something that doesn't work, catch expects a function that will do something with the error